# What operations of spark is processed in parallel?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, rdd

I am trying to wrap my head about the whole concept of spark. I think I have a very rudimentary understanding about spark platform. From what I understand, Spark has the concept of RDDs which is a collection of "stuff" in memory so processing is faster. You **transform** RDDs by using methods like map and flatmaps. Since transformations are **lazy**, they are not processed until you call an action on the final RDD. What I am unclear about is, when you do an action, are the transformations run in parallel? Can you assign workers to do the `action` in parallel?

For example, lets say I have a text file that I load into an RDD,

```
lines = //loadRDD
lines.map(SomeFunction())
lines.count()
```

What is actually going on? Does SomeFunction() process a partition of the RDD? What is the parallel aspect?

Comment: `RDD.map` is a transformation returning a new RDD. In this example, it achieves nothing: (1) you are not using that transformed RDD. (2) this means the map will never execute - as you said, transformations are lazy. (3) map cannot change the result of `count`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lines` is just a name for the RDD data structure resident in the driver which represents a partitioned list of rows. The `partitions` are being managed at each of your worker nodes when they are needed.

When your action `count` is called, Spark works backwards through the tasks to perform that action, resulting in a section of the file being read (a `partition`), `SomeFunction` being serialised and sent over the network to the workers, and executed on each row. If you have lots of workers then more than one partition can be read at a time and `SomeFunction` can be mapped over a  partition for each worker/core.

Each worker sends the count of items for the partition it has processed back to the driver and the driver can sum up the counts from all the partitions and return the total.

Note: in your example, SomeFunction is redundant with respect to the count of items.

Comment: Let me see if I understand this, RDDs are split into partitions so when you call some transformation, let say SomeFunction(), SomeFunction() will run in parallel processing each RDD partition?

Comment: The transformation is `map`. map transforms each row of the RDD with a function `SomeFunction`. A task to run the map with the SomeFunction payload gets distributed to each worker and the worker runs the map (transforming each row according to SomeFunction) over each local partition. A picture would make this really clear!

Answer (score 1):

An `RDD` is an abstraction over your data as distributed among the cluster. It allows you to perform operations on it and not have to think about which node each piece is on.

With any distributed computation engine, certain operations will be parallelized across the cluster and others will require that the data be aggregated or reduced down to a single machine in some way. You happen to provide two excellent examples.

`map` is a trivially distributable command. Lets say you have some data A1, A2, and A3 which Spark distributes over three nodes, N1, N2, and N3, respectively. Calling `map(someFunction())` on the dataset will let N1 apply `someFunction` to all of the elements in A1 while all the other nodes do the same.

`count`, while it can be broken up "N1, count up all the data you have", ends up needing to return a single value to a single node. In Spark terminology, `collect`ing the data. Granted, count is really, really fast, but you can also force the RDD to store all the data on a single node (I've used this for output formatting and similar).

So, the ones that can be run in parallel are parallelized, and the ones that are not wait and then group the data in some way. Spark has all sorts of optimizations under the hood (which I'm just beginning to learn) of course to make sure it's fast.

Final disclaimer, I'm not a Spark core engineer and this is a really high level answer. I'm sure there are core contributors who could speak to the specifics of how commands are parallelized in much more detail.